# OpenCV: Framebuffer in 5-6-5, how to load in a Mat?

Tags: image, opencv, rotation

I am trying to do some manipulations on images using OpenCV.

I am receiving a stream of images in RGB 5-6-5 and I would like to rotate them 90 clockwise and 90 counter-clockwise.

I have written code to convert it from RGB 5-6-5 to ARGB 8-8-8-8 (32 bits) so that I can load into a Mat of CV_8UC4 but after the rotation, it looks a bit jerky.

Does anyone have a good solution on how I could rotate a 5-6-5 image please? I am always rotating by 90 degress or -90 (width becomes height and vice versa), so I should stay the same quality.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I figured out a nice solution: choosing CV_16UC1 works fine. I can then do a transpose() followed by a flip(). Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks mevatron. I had to wait a certain time before being able to submit it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a nice solution: choosing CV_16UC1 works fine. I can then do a transpose() followed by a flip(). Works like a charm!